# How to copy files to another directory using c++ filesystem library

Tags: c++, filesystems

I'm attempting to automate some image processing, and once I have processed an image I would like to move it to another directory.

I have tried using std::experimental::filesystem::copy and std::experimental::filesystem::copy_file, but I get an error of "Could not copy file: copy_file(p1, p2, options): invalid arguments: operation not permitted"

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

if (argc < 2) {
    cout << "no directory specified" << endl;
    return 0;
}

experimental::filesystem::path inputPath(argv[1]);
experimental::filesystem::path

for (auto const & entry : experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(inputPath)) {
    string src = entry.path().string();
    experimental::filesystem::path dest("C:\\Users\\Keelan\\Desktop\\MatchTest\\IMG_Copy\\"+ entry.path().filename().string());
    cout << entry.path() << endl;
    cout << "Copying " << src << " to " << dest << endl;
    experimental::filesystem::copy_file(entry.path(), dest, experimental::filesystem::copy_options::none);
}

return 0;
```

}

I have so far had no success using the either of these copy functions. I have seen other solutions involving redirecting file-streams but I don't think this is appropriate given I will be processing files on demand and need to minimise response time.

EDIT: the folder I'm copying to exists and all users have read/write permissions

EDIT 2: I deleted and recreated the folder and the problem is fixed, not sure of the reason why

Comment: Does the destination path exist and is writable for the user executing the code?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis yes and yes

Comment: I just ran your sample code and found 2 issues - since you haven't mentioned anything about how you handle existing files or nested directories i think the issue is caused by one of the points mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 potential issues here:

1. Since you use `experimental::filesystem::copy_options::none` you will get an exception if the file already exists - see the paragraph "Otherwise, if the destination file already exists" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file)
2. If the source folder contains subfolders with files, the `directory_iterator` will iterate them as well, but if you attempt to copy a file nested deeper, you need to create the target directory hierarchy as well.

Comment: That's valid, but I am assuming that there isn't already an existing file, and the files I'm copying with all be in one directory, there will be no sub-directories

Comment: What I mean to say is, these are not causing the problem. Unless you're saying I can fix this by changing copy_options?

Comment: @KeelanPool so neither of these 2 issues are present? No matching files are present in the target directory, and there are no subdirectories in the source folder? Can you maybe trigger the exception with a source folder with a single file and post the layout of the source and target directories?

Comment: nope, neither of those issues are happening at the moment. I will change the code to account for already existing files later on though so thanks for that :P The layout is MatchTest contains two folders, one is IMG, the other is IMG_Copy (I'm passing in the path of the IMG directory as a command line argument currently)